# Issues with Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User

Tags: proxy, gecko

I have the following code:

```
    Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.type") = 1
    Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.share_proxy_settings") = True
    Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.https") = "000.000.000.000"
    Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.https_port") = 80
    Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.https_remote_dns") = True
```

In which `000.000.000.000` is a proxy.

The problem is sometimes it works and most of the time is not affected.

How can I see if the proxy IP is affected to the `network.proxy.https`? Also, how can I force the change of the proxy and the port?

One other problem:

Sometimes where I am using `geckowebbrowser` it sends a message box with choice answer, like:

> Would you really like to quit this page?

How can I escape this message box and others?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new to GeckoFX, but I know that in the latest version (31.0), Skybound doesn't exist anymore. You may have some luck by upgrading to the latest version. Here is the link to the repo: https://bitbucket.org/geckofx